# Fractional scaling not working with Gnome 3.34

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I'm struggling with the fractional scaling feature in gnome.

My current setup:
Display1: 2736x1824 (on a surface pro 6)
Display2: 1920x1080
Display3: 1920x1080

I've configured the scale for Display1 to 200%. But the current solution is disappointing.
I've tried following scenarios:

***Display1 scaled to 200%, Display2/3 to 100%, primary display = Display3:***
Windows are correctly display on Display2/3, Display1 doesn't scale anything except gnome-own applications.
[The surface screen looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvyXK.png)

***Display1 scaled to 200%, Display2/3 to 100%, primary display = Display1:***
All looks good on the surface now, all applications are scaled correctly. But all windows on display2/3 are scaled double, except gnome own application.

[The surface screen looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTrFZ.png)
[Display3 looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cZ62.png)

***Display1 scaled to 200%, Display2&3 not connected:***
All is working fine!

I've already deleted the `~/.config/monitors.xml` to give it try.
And the surface was rebooted many times.

Any ideas how to solve the issue?

A friend of mine has the same setup and it works for him. We didn't find any difference in our setup.

I'm completely lost for now, any help would be great!

Comment: Fractional scaling is still experimental. If you have an issue you can report the bug on the GNOME gitlab page: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/issues

Comment: thx, I've opened an issue... nevertheless the confusing thing is that is works on my colleague's surface. same device, same os, ...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to be using Wayland to use the experimental fractional scaling feature. This admittedly caught me as I've recently setup a second user account and went through enabling the experimental fractional scaling, but didn't see it come into effect.

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/06/enable-fractional-scaling-ubuntu-19-04 describes how to setup fractional scaling.

The default login is not Wayland so on logging in, click the cog icon next to the Signup button and choose the Ubuntu on Wayland option.